# Problem in my model LSTM loss: 81.84% for my validation data

Tags: keras, deep-learning, lstm

please help me in my problem , I don't have any one to help me!!
this is my code

```
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset) - look_back - 1):
        a = dataset[i:(i + look_back), :]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 7])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)

dataframe = pandas.read_csv('datatem1.csv', engine='python') 
dataset = dataframe.values
# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67) 
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size, :], dataset[train_size:len(dataset), :]
look_back = 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)  
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)
# reshape input to be  [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], look_back, 8))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0],look_back, 8))
# create and fit the LSTM network
model1 = tf.keras.Sequential()
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True, input_shape=(look_back,8)))
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=False))
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2))
model1.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
model1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
history1= model1.fit(trainX, trainY,validation_data=(testX, testY), epochs=50, batch_size=30,callbacks=[tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir="logs\{}".format("LSTM"), histogram_freq=1, profile_batch = 100000000)])
```

In my problem binary classifier i have file data collecting  from sensors each line contain date heure var1, var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7,output(that have 0 or 1)
In my model i want to predict an output at time t but by taking into consideration  the realsvalors of var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6,var7 at time t  (not at t-1)
(date and hour i drop it from file) when i make look_back=1(timestep) it'is ok val_loss=13% and accuracy=92%
but when i make timestep=5 loss: 81.84% why? is my code correct?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2o0aA.png)

Comment: could you explain your question with more detail, i cannot understand your problem exactly . Also, show minimum sample of your data, how it look like ?

Comment: @Mari i make picture in initial post from lines in my file

Comment: You sound confused; loss is not expressed in percentages (%) - accuracy does, but not loss

Comment: By the way, losses are not percentages.

Comment: because in my programm i added``` scores = model1.evaluate (testX, testY, verbose = 0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model1.metrics_names[0], scores[0]*100))
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model1.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100)) ```

Comment: @Mari  can some one help me